# two TextView next to each other

Tags: android, textview

I am currently using two TextViews, one to display Heading and other to display the Title. Currently they look like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdPhR.png)

But I want to achieve something like :[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2MBi.png)

Is it possible to achieve the consecutive lines using two TextViews without having to use the HTML formatting? If yes, then what is the possible solution?

my test.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="This is a Title :  "
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="here is my text that it's about the title.this is a very larg text and it "
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" />
```

Comment: Please update the code of your XML file too

Comment: And you want it to be like first link or second link, I am still not clear about it.

Comment: Any reason why you use two textViews? Why not merge them into one textView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take only one `TextView` like @Aman mentioned, if you want to style them differently use the `Spannable` interface. Its pretty powerful. Here is the example http://androidcocktail.blogspot.hk/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void initTopInfo(){

        Spannable word1 = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.test1));
        Spannable word2 = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.test2));

        word2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)), 0, word2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        word2.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("main", "word2 clicked");

            }
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
                ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
            }
        }, 0, word2.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        textView1.setText(word1);
        textView1.append(word2);


    }
```

xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=""/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Result

[image]

Comment: do it this way, you can have one textview , and multiple fonts, different click listeners and style. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Take only one `TextView` and append the text for title and the subtitle in that `TextView`

Comment: You can change the textsize and textcolor for the same textview using Html.fromHtml(). Take a look at here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html
OR
you can use spannable string

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="This is a title:"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".75"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:text="here is my text that it's about the title.this is a very larg text and it"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: code is working change your relative layout to linearlayout

Comment: It will never work. @ZeeshanKhan please look at his desire output.

Answer (score 0):

In your strings file

```
<string name="test"><b>This is heading in bold : </b><i>This is explanation in italics</i></string>
```

In your XML, use single TextView as

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test" />
```

I don't think you can achieve it without HTML, and its impossible to get that particular stuff with two TextViews

Answer (score 0):

Please Take Only one TextView and while you manipulate text through java file and append title and your other code

please check this code hope you help it

**this is your layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="This is a Title :  here is my text that it's about the title.this is a very larg text and it"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**And Here is Your java File**

```
public class TestingActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.title_layout);


        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);


        String text = "This is a Title :" +
                "here is my text that it's about the title.this is a very larg text and it";


        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok. now how I set a color for Title and a color for the other?

Comment: Please use this way

    String text = "<font color=#cc0029>This is a Title :</font> <font color=#ffcc00>here is my text that it's about the title.this is a very larg text and it</font>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

Comment: I said "I dont want use html".anyway thanks for your help. I used spannable for that.

Comment: you can do this way


TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);
 Spannable word = new SpannableString("Your message");        

 word.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

 TV.setText(word);
 Spannable wordTwo = new SpannableString("Your new message");        

 wordTwo.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, wordTwo.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 TV.append(wordTwo);